# adb: No such file or directory

Tags: android, cocos2d, adb

Пытаюсь запустить проект на движке cocos2dx под Android.

Вроде все правильно настроил: поставил Android SDK, NDK, Java, Ant. И adb тоже ставил, т.к. `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb` пишет, что уже установлена новейшая версия. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$ adb devices
bash: /home/maxim/android-sdks//platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory
```

Comment: А указанный файл вообще существует, может в этом и проблема?

Comment: напрягают два слеша в пути. Проверьте это...

Comment: @metalurgus да 2 слеша были лишними, но все равно ничего не изменилось и странно то, что файл там есть и то что до этого, эта функция работала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gedit .bashrc** в помощь, посмотри в переменной окружения путь и в крайнем случае пропиши полный путь

Answer (score 0):

```
locate -r ~/".*platform-tools/adb"
```

Выдаст правильный путь до директории, которую ищешь, если она существует.